# Prompt Ops Alternatives

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, prompt, large-language-model

What are the main alternatives for prompt ops nowadays? By prompt ops, I mean a comprehensive solution for tracking prompt engineering experiments and also registering prompts in different stages, similar to how I would with an ML model in a model registry.

I went through MLFLow and it seems to have somehow what I look for, instead Sagemaker has tracking prompt experiments features, but it seems to allow prompt registration just using a "fake Estimator" object, that's not a very clean solution. Please correct me if there is another option for SageMaker I did not go through.